# how to fix wrong stack alignment with Eigen library under Workbench3.0 (vxworks 6.6 IDE)

Tags: gcc, stack, eigen, memory-alignment, vxworks

I am using **Eigen(3.2.0)** Library under **Workbench3.0 (vxworks 6.6)**. The compiler in this distribution is **GCC version 4.1.2**.

Language : **c++**; Operating System: **winXP**

the problem code is as followed:

```
Eigen::Matrix3d mOrigin;
/* initial mOrigin */
...
Eigen::Quaterniond qOrigin(mOrigin);
```

I debuged the program and found that when it runs :

```
Eigen::Quaterniond qOrigin(mOrigin);
```

it comes out the assertion and prints:

> > *assertion failed: (reinterpret_cast(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " ******** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!
> >     ! ********" in function Eigen::internal::plain_array::plain_array() [with T = double, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0] at C:/WindRiver-GPPVE-3.6-IA-Eval/vxworks-6.6/target/h/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:78*

it said, fixed-size vectorizable Eigen objects must absolutely be created at 16-byte-aligned locations, otherwise SIMD instructions adressing them will crash. And that is why the assertion arises.

I think the problem is:
**Compiler making a wrong assumption on stack alignment**
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicWrongStackAlignment.html

it said, **It appears that this was a GCC bug that has been fixed in GCC 4.5. If you hit this issue, please upgrade to GCC 4.5 and report to us, so we can update this page.**

However, GCC is the intergation compiler of Workbench and I don't know how to upgrade it.
And I think I have tested the *Local Solution* and *Global Solution*, but they don't work.

### *Local Solution:*

add *"__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer))"*

```
class Interpolation : public InterpMath/*,public Colleague*/
{
 public:
     EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
     ...
     __attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer)) ErrorID LineInterp(
            const Position_MCS_rad &targetPoint,
            const Position_MCS_rad &originPoint,
            const Position_ACS_rad &originACS,
            double Ts, double maxVel, double maxAcc,
            double maxDecel, double maxJerk,
            N_AxisSeqPtr &nAglSeqPtr, GrpTcpSeq *pGrpTcp = NULL)
     {
          Eigen::Matrix3d mOrigin;
          /* initial mOrigin */
         ... 
         Eigen::Quaterniond qOrigin(mOrigin);
     }
}
```

> > *warning: 'force_align_arg_pointer' attribute directive ignored*

### *Global Solution:*

add compile option *-mstackrealign*

> > **ccpentium** -g -mtune=pentium4 -march=pentium4 -ansi -Wall   -MD -MP **-Xlinker -mstackrealign**  -IC:/WindRiver-GPPVE-3.6-IA-Eval/vxworks-6.6/target/h -IC:/WindRiver-GPPVE-3.6-IA-Eval/vxworks-6.6/target/h/wrn/coreip -IC:/WindRiver-GPPVE-3.6-IA-Eval/workspace/RobotInterface_2_2/h   -DCPU=PENTIUM4 -DTOOL_FAMILY=gnu -DTOOL=gnu -D_WRS_KERNEL    -o

So how can I upgrade the intergration compiler to gcc 4.5 or newer, or whether there is other solution to fix this problem ?

Thanks for reading and help.

Comment: The Eigen page in the error message describes how to turn off vectorization. Is that too slow? And then the error seems to have to do with alignment of objects on the stack, so generally using dynamically allocated Eigen objects may fix the prob already.

Comment: Your compiler is too old to get good vectorization, so in the meantime you can safely disable vectorization.

Comment: Thanks for the tips of you and @PeterSchneider . I followed your both advice and got rid of that assertion by completely disabling vectorization. The performance of program seems all right for requirements. Thank you both a lot!